# How to compile and "register" an XPCOM component with latest Gecko SDK in Windows?

Tags: firefox, xpcom

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://ptncode.blogspot.com/2013/08/exposing-xpcom-c-interface-on-dom.html) with the latest Gecko SDK(at this moment, the latest version is xulrunner-sdk 31.0).  And I'd like to do it with Visual Studio 10 in a separate location.

Right now, I managed to get the code compiled though I'm not sure the dll is actually functional. I packed everything into an [xpi package](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7VQMP8bMIXldlcwMXFRcTJvM3M/edit?usp=sharing) and installed it on Firefox for testing. It works for createInstance(); however, it fails when inquiry for the interface. the error message: 
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004002 (NS_NOINTERFACE) [nsISupports.QueryInterface]"  nsresult: "0x80004002 (NS_NOINTERFACE)"  location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code ::  :: line 1"  data: no]

I looked into the dll with depend walk, and the only function show up is NSModule.  Can anyone take a look on the files and let me know where the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: Update: I switched to follow another sample:

Comment: Give us link if it works, please :)

Comment: After chatting with developers on moznet, I reached the conclusion that it is not worth the time and effort to create an XPCOM component with C++ anymore.